Absorption spectra in films chemicals & dyes
For a science competition, we have to understand absorption spectra in films chemicals & dyes. But what is that? I've found resources on the absorption spectra of chlorophyll, but I'm unclear as to what this means. Does anybody know what this means? I'm not asking this as a homework question, as my season has ended, but I'm curious as to what this means as my studying for this event has ended.

I think your overarching question is "what is an absorption spectra?" which I'll try to answer here by placing it into the context of how they are obtained.
A spectrum in optics is a continuous set of colors, quantified by its wavelength. For example, a green laser pointer is usually 532 nanometers, where 532 nanometers is its wavelength, or distance between the crests or troughs in the wave, this chemistry libretexts link has a nice picture. A different color will have a different wavelength -- blue is about 475 nanometers, and red is around 700 nanometers.
Since you are looking at the spectrum of chlorophyll, it was probably measured over the visible light spectrum, or about 400 to 700 nanometers (blue to red colors) in measured wavelengths. The wavelengths of light measured should make up the x-axis of the absorption spectrum you're looking at.
So then, the question becomes "what am I measuring at each wavelength in my spectrum?" or in other words, what is my y-axis in the absorption spectrum? It is what it says on the tin -- If I know how much light of a certain color (or wavelength) I started with, then I measure how much light of that particular color I lose (or is absorbed) by whatever I am looking at, then I know the absorbance of my object at that color.
To quantify the amount of light lost, we simply do the measurement I mentioned in the previous paragraph, and take the ratio:
$$T=\frac{I_L}{I_0} $$
Where T is the transmittance of the thing I am looking at, $I_L$ is the amount of remaining light at the color I chose, and $I_0$ is the amount of light at that color I started with. To get the absorbance (A), we take the $-log_{10}$ of the transmittance:
$$A=-log_{10}(T)=-log_{10}\left( \frac{I_L}{I_0} \right)$$
And this gives us our y-axis. Repeating this measurement many times over many different colors allows us to make the absorption spectrum you are looking at, or the amount of light something absorbs over a set of wavelengths.
I want to end with giving you some sense of scale on the y-axis, since it can be unintuitive to work in a logarithmic scale. Using the definition for the absorbance I gave, an absorbance of 1 means that the object you're looking at absorbed 90% of the light sent onto it. An absorbance of 2 is 99% of light absorbed, and an absorbance of 3 is 99.9% of light absorbed (see the pattern?). Finally, an absorbance of 0.5 means the object absorbed 70% of the light at that color.
I hope this helps clarify the meaning of absorption spectra, and is the answer to the question you're asking.

Thank you, that helps, but do you know what it means by absorption spectra in films, chemicals and dyes? Thanks for your effort

Each "object" will have its own absorption spectrum. So without totally understanding the context of "films, chemicals, and dyes", I would assume you are referring to the absorption spectrum of a particular film, or a particular chemical, or a particular dye.
